# What is typically involved on the ISP's behalf when you increase bandwidth on a leased line

Tags: isp, internet

We have a leased line with Virgin Media. It's a 100Mbit/s circuit but we're only currently paying/using for 10Mbit/s. We want to increase the speed and have been quoted a 10 working day turnaround which rather surprised me.

What is typically involved in increasing bandwidth on a leased line? I believed, possibly incorrectly, that it was a paperwork exercise plus a software re-configuration to adjust the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

From technical view, it just requires configuration adjustment on the bandwidth controlling node assuming the ISP has already acquired enough bandwidth to serve customers. Also, it may require a change in the billing plan.

From non-technical view, it may need some paper work and to communicate with other parties. This depends on much your ISP owns from the infrastructure and usuall procedure that should be followed and other involved parties.

Comment: +1. It could simply be they need additional capacity upstream (which CAN take time) or keep reserves for paperwork.

Comment: don't they provide cable tv programs, I wouldn't say they were an ISP in the sense of the word.

Comment: It's not unusual for ISPs to send out a technician to test some or all of the physical cables involved between your house and the exchange.  Scheduling this technician seems to be what takes the greatest amount of time.

Comment: Virgin Media are both a cable TV and internet provider. I've been with them personally for 10+ years and professionally at work for nearly 2 years and the service has been rock solid! <5ms speedtest to the nearest test node is the norm